# Writing log file while reading it with Excel or Notepad

Tags: c#, file, stream

I'm writing to a log file with this stream :

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Folder, LogFile),
                                      FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                                      FileAccess.Write,
                                      FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
   using(System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs))
   {
      while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
      {          
         file.WriteLine("bla bla bla");
      }
   }
}
```

The purpose of this code sample is to write into a log file. What I would like to be able to do is to read it with Excel or notepad while this code is running. I can open the file externally with Excel, but the file is empty until I stop the program.
Furthermore, when I try to open it with Excel, I am said that the file is locked for editing although I declared the stream with the `FileShare.ReadWrite`.

Comment: within your while loop after the file.WriteLine, issue an immediate `file.Flush();`

Comment: Excellent! That's what I was looking for ! You could post a reply if you want your answer to be approved...

Comment: I posted a fix for you thanks and glad that this was a quick and simple fix that I spotted immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when writing files in a while loop and you want to see the data real time for example in `NotePad` you need to immediately `Flush the data` in your case a simple

```
file.Flush();
```

inside of the while loop after the `file.Write` will work

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Folder, LogFile),
                                      FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                                      FileAccess.Write,
                                      FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
   using(System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs))
   {
      while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
      {          
         file.WriteLine("bla bla bla");
         file.Flush();
      }
   }
}
```